# How do I align my list-style-image with the text in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I was using bootstrap 4 and I am trying to align my list style image with the list style text.

So far here's my html:

```css
li.nav-item {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 15px 0px;
  list-style-image: url("../img/circle.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  list-style-position: left top;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav flex-column">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active">Text here text here text here</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link">Text here text here text here</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link">Text here text here text here</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link">Text here text here text here</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I've tried to used vertical align but it did not work. Also playing around with padding and margin too. Please help!

Comment: You have `margin: 15px 0px;` and `margin-left: 25px;`... one may prevent the other. Also... have you tried `margin-top: --px !important;` ?

Comment: for the demo could you change the text color (now it's white and none can see the text) and add an image from exiting url? (just that people can see your problem too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know about `list-style-image`  but you should try this:

```
li.nav-item {
    color: #000;
    margin: 15px 0px;
    list-style: none;
    background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sqpurple.gif) left center no-repeat;
    padding-left: 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```